# Mealy sequential network in behavioral model using verilog

Tags: verilog, hardware

How to Design a Mealy sequential network which investigates an input sequence X
and produces an output Z which is determined by two rules. The initial output
from the network is Z=0. Thereafter, the output Z will equal the preceding
value of X (rule 1) until the input sequence 010 occurs. Starting with the next
input after 010, the output Z will equal the complement of the present value
of X (rule 2) until the sequence 101 occurs. Starting with the next input after
101, the network output is again determined by rule 1, etc. Note that
overlapping 010 and 101 sequences may occur. Example:

Rule: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2
a.i.1.a.i. X= 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
a.i.1.a.ii. Z= 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

umm, draw a state diagram and start coding?